# Find all possible values of $\lambda$ which satisfy the given equation.

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

The question is to find the values of a real number $\lambda$ for which the following equation is satisfied for all real values of $\alpha$ which are not integral multiples of $\pi/2$
$${\sin\lambda\alpha\over \sin\alpha}-{\cos\lambda\alpha\over \cos\alpha}=\lambda-1$$

All I could do was to guess some values that just came to mind by observation, like $-1,1,3$

What should be a more mathematical way to find all possible values of $\lambda$?

SOURCE: KVPY 2015 SB stream

Comment: KVPY 2015 is now over, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Cross multiplying gives
$$
\sin((\lambda - 1)\alpha) = \frac{(\lambda -1)}{2}\sin(2\alpha) \qquad (\ast)
$$
Since both sides are continuously differentiable (as functions of $\alpha$), we obtain
$$
\cos((\lambda - 1)\alpha) = \cos(2\alpha)
$$
At $\alpha = \pi/4$, we get
$$
\cos((\lambda - 1)\pi/4) = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \lambda -1 \in \{2,-2,6,-6,10,-10, \ldots\}
$$
Also $\lambda = 1$ is clearly a solution to $(\ast)$, so we get
$$
\lambda \in \{1,3,7,11,\ldots\}\cup\{-1,-5,-9,\ldots\}
$$

Comment: Why did you put $\alpha=\pi/4$?

Answer (score 0):

To validate as an identity for all real $\alpha$

$$
\sin((\lambda - 1)\alpha) = \frac{(\lambda -1)}{2}\sin(2\alpha) \qquad 
$$

we are allowed to take small $\alpha$ values  $ \sin x \approx x $

A root as stationary point/ singular solution exists for all  $\alpha$ is obtained as :

$ \lambda - 1=0 , \lambda = 1 $

For other solutions around  this point we have to numerically find roots like for the roots of : $ \tan x = a \cdot x ,$  tangent curve cutting variable slope line.

Shall add to this soon.